# Amazon Route 53 & Emails with Microsoft Outlook 365

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, exchange-server, amazon-route53

I have setup my website with Amazon EC2 and Route53 successfully. Our company decided to go with Microsoft Exchange for their email.

Microsoft online told me to add a TXT and MX record in the DNS registry. Works great! Can now send emails. However when people sometimes email me from a Google account (known, there could be other servies I don't know about) They receive an error like this:

```
This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification

THIS IS A WARNING MESSAGE ONLY.

YOU DO NOT NEED TO RESEND YOUR MESSAGE.

Delivery to the following recipient has been delayed:

    [[EMAIL_ADDRESS]]

Message will be retried for 1 more day(s)

Technical details of temporary failure: 
DNS Error: Domain name not found
```

Do you know how I can fix this. My web address is visible and working and some people can send me emails fine but others get this.

**UPDATE: DNS RECORDS**

```
+----------------------+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| charterbox.com.au.   | A   | 54.252.90.224                                                                               |   3600 |
| charterbox.com.au.   | MX  | 0 ms36130019.msv1.invalid.outlook.com                                                       |   3600 |
| charterbox.com.au.   | NS  | ns-1099.awsdns-09.org. ns-138.awsdns-17.com. ns-830.awsdns-39.net. ns-1960.awsdns-53.co.uk. | 172800 |
| charterbox.com.au.   | SOA | ns-1099.awsdns-09.org. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400               |    900 |
| charterbox.com.au.   | TXT | "MS=ms36130019"                                                                             |   3600 |
| *.charterbox.com.au. | A   | 54.252.90.224                                                                               |    300 |
+----------------------+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

Comment: So you're able to succesfully send email to your domain from another email provider?  It sounds like you have a DNS record misconfigured.  Can you post your dns records?

Comment: So it looks like its most external domains that get that rejected email. Internal emails are set fine. I have updated with the DNS records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MX record you have in place looks like the record used to verify your domain.  You will need to change it to the production mx records.  You can find the specific value(s) for your domain in the domain administration section of the admin page at portal.microsoftonline.com.  Once you update the MX records, you should be good to go.

Comment: Ok thanks. Do I leave the validation record in or should I take that out?

Comment: I would just put whatever they have in the admin page.  You don't want bad MX records, especially with a 0 weight.

Comment: @Edwin hi. did you solve this problem? 
I have it too and idk what to do.

Comment: @ElectricWizard I think my answer solved the problem.  Have you looked at your dns entries?

Comment: @Edwin This is what I added to route 53 - http://i.stack.imgur.com/hPJPu.png I just cant find what's he problem, 365 isn't recognizing it.